# Should I Use Multiple Targets or Separate Xcode Projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, projects, targets

I am making a food menu app for 3 separate restaurants but the app code is mostly the same for each one, just different content. Does it make more sense to use multiple targets in Xcode to manage this, in terms of keeping code updated across apps when updating it in the future? Or would having multiple separate Xcode projects make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Single project, separate targets is the simplest solution that will get the job done.

Create one target for each client app via File -> New -> Target.  After you do that, you will be able to select the individual files, and check the box inside the Inspector pane to include them in whatever target(s): shared code would have every box checked.

When you create the targets, Xcode will automatically create a scheme to build each one.[image]